# STL Vectors, pointers and classes

Tags: c++, stl, pointers, vector

Let's say i have 2 classes:

```
class Class1
{
public:
  std::vector<CustomClass3*> mVec;
public:
  Class1();
  ~Class1()
  {
    //iterate over all the members of the vector and delete the objects
  }
};

class InitializerClass2
{
private:
  Class1 * mPtrToClass1;
public:
  InitializerClass2();
  void Initialize()
  {
    mPtrToClass1->mVec.push_back(new CustomClass3(bla bla parameters));
  }
};
```

Will this work? Or the memory allocated in the InitializerClass2::Initialize() method might get corrupted after the method terminates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short this will work fine.

The memory being allocated in Initialize is on the heap. This means that changes in the stack do not affect the contents of this memory.

Comment: so, this:
void Initialize()
{
    mPtrToClass1->mVec.push_back(new CustomClass3(bla bla parameters));
}

is different from this:
void Initialize()
{
    CustomClass3* tempPtr= new CustomClass3(bla bla);
    mPtrToClass1->mVec.push_back(tempPtr));
}
Because in the second case, i think, "tempPtr" get's deleted after method's termination and the memory might get overwritten. Right?

Comment: @anubis9: wrong. In c++ there is no automated lifetime management of raw pointers. In neither of the cases the object will be deleted when the method exits.

Answer (score 2):

One issue I see with `Class1` is that it is not copy safe yet the copy and assignment constructors have not been suppressed.

This can cause a problem because the destructor of `Class1` is noted as freeing the memory for all items in `mVec`.  Using the implicit operator this means that you'd end up with 2 instances of `Class1` pointing to the same `CustomClass3` instances and the second destructor would be double deleting memory.  For example

```
Class c1;
c1.mVec.push_back(new CustomClass3(...));
Class c2 = c1;
```

In this case the second destructor to run (c1) will be freeing an already deleted `CustomClass3` instance.  You should disable copy construction and assignment for `Class1` to prevent this

```
class Class1 { 
  ...
private:
  Class1(const Class1&);
  Class1& operator=(const Class1&);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work (provided `mPtrClass1` is a valid pointer of course).

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that in your InitializerClass2 that you change the constructor to the following:

```
InitializerClass2() : mPtrToClass1(NULL){}
~InitializerClass2(){
    if( mPtrToClass1 != NULL) delete mPtrToClass1;
}

void Initialize(){
    if( mPtrToClass1 == NULL){
        mPtrToClass1 = new InitializerClass1();
    }

    mPtrToClass1->mVec.push_back(new CustomClass3(bla bla parameters) );
}
```

if you're not going to use RAII, so that you don't get issues with checking the destructor.

As to your question, see where I added in the new operator.  YOu're not initializing your variable.

Comment: Your suggestions are valid. However, the mPtrToClass1 initialization should probably happen in the constructor. The poster might be assuming that it does. Creating a new instance of Class1 in initialize is a little strange. Calling Initialize repeatedly will cause a memory leak.

Comment: The NULL check on mPtrToClass1 is unnecessary. delete is specified to do that.

Comment: actually yes, the constructors are all ok, i just did not write it here, because i'm interested just in the Initialize() method where i allocate the memory and push it into the vector of mPtrToClass1.

Comment: @Steve Fallows - depends on which compiler you're using.

Comment: you mean a standards compliant one or not? :)